# Get rid of white highlight in Dolphin with mouse over

Tags: themes, kde, gtk, dolphin

Hello I'm trying to get rid of the white highlight in Dolphin that happens when you go over something with your mouse. I tried editing `sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`, but can't figure out where that setting is. I would post an image, but the forum won't let me. Link to pic is:

[image]

Home is where the mouse is.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted at [when I select a file in dolphin the name disappears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153201/when-i-select-a-file-in-dolphin-the-name-disappears) worked for me.

It is:

Please change (with root-priviliges) a line in the following file:

> `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

from

> `selected_fg_color:#ffffff`

to

> `selected_fg_color:#000000`

(it is on the first line of this file)

I used this setting but haven't tested it extensively in other apps:

```
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#ffffff\nselected_bg_color:#80f080\nselected_fg_color:#a00000\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nbg_color:#F2F1F0\ntooltip_bg_color:#000000\nlink_color:#DD4814"
```